# Why clear: right doesn't work as intended

Tags: css, css-float

I'm always confused by `clear: left`, `clear: right` and `clear: both` in CSS. I know `clear: both` means it doesn't allow floating elements on both sides of itself.

I did some testing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/malaikuangren/xqFUL/1/). I thought the layout would appear like below, because `B` uses `clear: both`. But it doesn't. Could someone tell me why?

A
B
CD

**Updated**
(Post the code)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="A">a</div>
    <div class="B">b</div>
    <div class="C">c</div>
    <div class="D">d</div>
    <div class="CB"></div>
</div>

.container{
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid red;    
}
.B{
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    width:10%;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.A,.C,.D{
    float:left;
    width:10%;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
.CB{
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: You should outline the code of your test case in the question as well - include the essential bits from the fiddle (sans sizing and borders etc.)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`clear` on an element only clears the floats *before* it in document order. It doesn't clear floats *after* it. The `left` and `right` values mean clearance of left floats and right floats *preceding an element* respectively. They don't mean clearing floats before and after the element.

Since C is being floated, but doesn't have any clearance being applied, it floats next to B. B does not try to clear C because C comes after it in the document structure.

Furthermore, `clear: right` doesn't have any effect in your test case because none of your elements are being floated to the right anyway.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks, that was the phrase I was looking for, added.

Comment: Thanks your edit and help,You answer is very clear and helpful. I like it . Now my understanding of it is better .

Answer (score 1):

You can have a clear that works after the div if you use:

```
.clr::after
{
 content: "";
 clear: both;
 display: block;
 height: 0;
 visibility: hidden;
}
```