# how to clear float the right img

Tags: html, css

i have two img and float them.like this

```css
img{
  float:left;
  clear:right;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://img1.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=1005212286,2432746147&fm=21&gp=0.jpg' alt=''>
<img src='http://img1.imgtn.bdimg.com/it/u=1005212286,2432746147&fm=21&gp=0.jpg' alt=''>
```

i am confused why right img still float behind the first img. i think the second img will go to next line.Can someone tell me why?

Comment: You have to clear left float not right with `clear:left;`.

Answer (score 2):

You are close!

```
img {
 float: left;
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: why i can't do it by my way. i want to know my missing

Comment: i would say in general a `clear:left;` or `clear:both;` is what is used with `float:left;` elements. you can read on this property here - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp

Comment: also see this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080073/why-clear-right-doesnt-work-as-intended

Comment: yeah if you change your css to `img { float: right; clear:right; }` it will work like you thought.